# CSS html and body containers aren't stretching to content's height

Tags: css, html, height, background-image

I've been reading a lot of entries to figure out why my content won't force the body and html tags to stretch to 100% of the inner content's height.

My page is here: http://truerenaissance.devmu.com/artisthighlight/

You'll see the background image (set on the body tag) is not stretching to 100% of the page or inner content's height. I am only using position: relative everywhere. I'm also using a 'clearfix' at the bottom of the content. 
If anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening, I'd really appreciate it.

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; background: white; font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'Arial'; }
#site-wrapper { width: 775px; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 100px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
        padding: 0px; z-index: 10; }
#site-wrapper .inner { min-height: 100%; padding: 20px 20px 40px 24px; }
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.clear:after {
    clear:both;
}
.fixer { display:block;clear:both;overflow:hidden;width:auto;height:0px;line-height:1px;font-size:1px; }

<html>
  <body>
    <div id="body-wrapper">
      <div id="site-wrapper">
       <div class="inner">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to keep the background image fixed?

Comment: I just want the background to fit the width, fully, no matter what the screeen size is (this is working now), and then I want the background image to be full height (not necessarily of the page, but at least itself), because the background image I'm using here probably won't stretch the full height of this page. I plan on editing the background image to put a fade at the bottom in this case. I also need the background container (the body in this case) to stretch to 100% of the page).

Comment: In that case remove `height:100%` of `#site-wrapper`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you constrained the body height to the viewport height and you didn't stretch the background vertically.
Remove `height: 100%` from `html` and `body` and use `background-size`'s `cover` value.

Thanks for the big-ass picture by the way.

Comment: Wow, didn't realize height: 100% only went to the height of the viewport. Learn something everyday. Thanks for the snide comment.

Comment: One more issue just popped up here. The original page I posted is working now, the background (body/html) stretches after removing height: 100%; However, now, on subsequent pages, if the content does not fit the entire height of the page, the background (body/html) does not stretch to the entire page (because I removed height: 100%). Is there anyway to get the background to stretch to the full height of the viewport, only when the content itself doesn't stretch. I would also like it to work in the original case, where the background does stretch to the contents height. Is this possible?

Comment: Here are the pages in question:
Original: http://truerenaissance.devmu.com/artisthighlight/
Other page where the content is short: http://truerenaissance.devmu.com/about/

Comment: Are you sure you kept `max: height: 100%;` on `html, body`? The pages doesn't load so it's all I can say now.